# A question about URLSessionDataTask and Combine in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, combine, nsurlsessiondatatask

In an [article](https://www.cocoawithlove.com/blog/separated-services-layer.html), I saw a code snippet like below:

```
extension URLSessionDataTask: Cancellable {}

extension URLSession: NetworkService {
   public func fetchData(with request: URLRequest, handler: @escaping (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void) -> AnyCancellable {
      let task = dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: handler)
      task.resume()
      return AnyCancellable(task)
   }
}
```

There are several things that I do not understand:

1. What is the purpose of making URLSessionDataTask conform to 'Cancellable' protocol;
2. If URLSessionDataTask conforms to 'Cancellable' protocol, why does not it implement the methods that 'Cancellable' protocol requires;
3. When I check the initialiser of AnyCancellable, there is no initialiser which accepts an argument, so what does 'AnyCancellable(task)' do here and is it correct?

Appreciate any help.

Comment: @bestiosdeveloper no, [Cancellable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/cancellable) is part of the Combine framework

Comment: I guess the purpose of making  URLSessionDataTask conform to Cancellable is so that the function can return a value that can be cancelled using AnyCancellable since this class implements cancel(). Point 3 is incorrect, see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/anycancellable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. What is the purpose of making URLSessionDataTask conform to 'Cancellable' protocol?

So that you could use `AnyCancellable`. `AnyCancellable` initializer only works with types conforming to `Cancellable`.

> 2. If URLSessionDataTask conforms to 'Cancellable' protocol, why does not it implement the methods that 'Cancellable' protocol requires;

`Cancallable` requires there to be a method `cancel` and `store(in:)`. `cancel` already exists on `URLSessionTask` - a base class of `URLSessionDataTask`, and `store(in:)` is implemented as an extension on `Cancellable` providing a default implementation.

> 3. When I check the initialiser of AnyCancellable, there is no initialiser which accepts an argument, so what does 'AnyCancellable(task)' do here and is it correct?

`AnyCancellable` has [`init(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/anycancellable/init(_:)-48fh3) that accepts a `Cancellable`

Comment: Hi @New Dev, thank you for the explanation. But I am not quite sure what do you mean by: 'and store(in:) is implemented as an extension on Cancellable providing a default implementation'. I checked the source code of 'Cancellable' and I did not see that store(in:) is implemented.

Comment: Where have you checked the source code of `Cancellable`? But also, with protocol extensions in Swift, anyone anywhere could provide a [default implementation](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Protocols.html#ID529).